# Не получается Parallax эффект при скроле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу сделать пераллакс эффект при прокрутке страници, нашел в нете как делаль, всё вро де бы правильно написал но эффекта как такового не появляется. Использую sass, поэтому в скрипте и прописал
            $(".parallax img").sass
подозреваю что не коректоно может работать скрипт из-за этого.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
            
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            
            
            $(".parallax img").sass({
                "transform" : "translate(0px, -" + st /20 + "%"
            });
            
        });
```

```css
.parallax {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}

.parallax img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="parallax">
        <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/7/22/29fde1bf8870f482406b77c1d469308b-full.jpg" alt="">
        
    </section>
```

Comment: a jQuery подключить не вариант? :)

Comment: @Demon __ ANT у меня jQuery подключен

Comment: тут не подключен jQuery

Comment: @Demon __ ANT подключил ну а смысл

Comment: У jQuery нет функции sass. Наверное всё-таки css, только с её использованием разберитесь.

Comment: @MAX Скорее всего ты прав, но когда пишу css, у меня эта картинка пропадает.

Comment: Ну и в translate похоже скобку потеряли.

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените:

```
$(".parallax img").sass({
            "transform" : "translate(0px, -" + st /20 + "%"
        });
```

на

```
$(".parallax img").css({
            "transform" : "translate(0px, -" + st /20 + "%"
        });
```